# How to print all the keys and values in a map to a single string?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have written the following code:

```
    String reqParams = null;

    Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();

    for (Object key : params.keySet()) {
        String keyStr = (String) key;
        String[] value = params.get(keyStr);
        reqParams = reqParams + ((String) key + "=" + Arrays.toString(value) + " ");
    }

   System.out.println(reqParams);
```

I have the following output:

```
  nullorderId=[01] orderStatus=[delivered]
```

1. How can I get rid of the `null` that prints at the beginning?
2. Is it possible to avoid the [ ] from printing?
3. How can I do this using streams?

Comment: *"How to print all the keys and values in a map to a single string?"* Have you tried `params.toString()`?

Comment: Why did you declare `key` as type `Object`, when the key is declared as type `String` in the `Map`? Change loop to `for (String key : params.keySet())` and eliminate those casts.

Comment: *"Is it possible to avoid the `[ ]` from printing?"* Yes, but what would you like output to be if the array has multiple values?

Comment: @Andreas that would print the object `org.apache.catalina.util.ParameterMap@5403f0ad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` operation and the `joining` collector:

```
String resultSet = 
          params.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + String.join(", ", e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

- `", "` is the delimiter if the array has more than one element.
- `" "` in the `joining` is the delimiter to separate the elements
  from the source.

Comment: Thank you. If the value is null for a given key, is it possible to print null?

Comment: @SkyBlue if the value of a given key is null then you'll get a `NullPointerException` as `String.join` disallows nullity for both the delimiter and the sequence passed in. do you want to print "null" if the value of a given key is null?

Comment: This prints `orderId=1 orderStatus=` If the orderStatus has no value.

Comment: @SkyBlue so when you say "no value" you mean if the value of a given key is an _empty array_ in which case yes that would be the result.  do you want the result as `orderId=1 orderStatus=null` if the array is empty?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant :)

Comment: @SkyBlue cool, in which case you want `params.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + 
                        (e.getValue().length == 0? null : String.join(", ", e.getValue())))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));`

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `reqParams` as an empty string. That is,

```
String reqParams = null;
```

becomes

```
String reqParams = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize reqParams like this : `String reqParams = ""` or don't append your string to redParams and just do this `reqParams = ((String) key + "=" + value[0] + " ");`
2. Just get the element in the array instead of turning the array into a String: `reqParams = reqParams + ((String) key + "=" + value[0] + " ");`
3. You could stream `params.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> .... )` and add a function in the forEach that appends the key and the value to a String like you're doing in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `join` method of the `String` class to turn the array into a String, avoiding the `[ ]` characters.  Also, you don't need all the casting and extra parentheses that you have in your original code, if you use `Map.Entry` with type parameters, and iterate through the entry set instead of the key set.

```
for( Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry : params.entrySet()) {
    reqParams = reqParams + entry.getKey() + "=" + String.join(",", entry.getValue()) + " ";
}
```

So here, `join` takes your array and separates all the elements with commas.

Lastly, if you initialise `reqParams` to `""` instead of `null`, then the word `null` won't print.

```
String reqParams = "";
```